# DomCrawler filterXpath not always giving full URL

Tags: php, goutte, domcrawler

For my project, I'm using [domcrawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) to parse pages and extract images.

Code:

```
$goutteClient = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
    'timeout' => 15,
));

$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);

try {
    $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', $url);
    $crawlerError = false;
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $crawlerError = true;
}

if ($crawlerError == false) {

    //find open graph image
    try {
        $file = $crawler->filterXPath("//meta[@property='og:image']")->attr('content');
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $file = null;
    }

    //if that fails, find the biggest image in the DOM      
    if (!$file) {
        $images = $crawler
        ->filterXpath('//img')
        ->extract(array('src'));    

        $files = [];
        foreach ($images as $image) {

            $attributes = getimagesize($image);
            //stopping here since this is where i'm getting my error
```

The relevant part is at the bottom. This will work some of the time. However, occasionally I get an error. For example, if `$url` was https://www.google.com it would spit out the following error:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   getimagesize(/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

If I `dd($image);` in this situation, `$image` equals `"/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png"`.

However, if I try with a website that doesn't give me an error, like https://www.harvard.edu, `dd($image);` returns `"https://www.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/feature_item_media/Kremer900x600.jpg"`

In other words, I'm not getting the full URL. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the relative links with the scheme and host. You can use `parse_url` on `$url` to extract the scheme and host, and can use the same function on `$image` to detect if a scheme/host is set.